# Am I using integrated or discrete graphics?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, ati, hybrid-graphics, gpu

My work station is a Macbook Pro which has...

- integrated graphics: Intel HD 3000
- discrete graphics: Radeon XXXX...

I have installed drivers for the discrete graphics right after installation.

During normal usage, I notice that the calculated time for the remaining battery life frequently changes significantly - therefore I assume that Ubuntu 12.04 switches between the integrated and discrete graphics.

However, the **indicated battery life only changes between 1:30 and 3 hours, which is significantly less than the 5-6 hours I get when using OSX 10.7.X**.

- Is *all* of this this due to an overhead caused by 'bad' drivers that I have to expect - or is it just that I'm using discrete graphics all the time?
- How can check what graphics I'm currently using?

Comment: If you install powertop and run `sudo powertop`, do you see lots of elements to improve in the `Tunables` section?

Comment: @130490868091234 I don't see a tunables section. [Here's a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uklahzu4mu2ebf1/powertop.png) of what I see when running `sudo powertop`.

Comment: If you move to the right with the arrow keys, it should be the last on the right.

Comment: @130490868091234  Ok :) Thanks! There are quite a lot of entries: [link to picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3grij4swymh6dn/tunables%20einstellbarkeit.png). schlecht=bad, gut=good

Comment: You can hit `Enter` on each of them, moving with the down arrow, and then check back the power usage after that (while unplugged).

Comment: @130490868091234 I've done that, but I cannot tell if that helps much. The reported power usage still moves between 18 an 21 watts. I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see what video drivers are being loaded by looking at the X server log in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Alternatively, the OpenGL renderer string.  For instance, on my desktop system I see:

```
$ glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL renderer string'
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD JUNIPER
```

Which is consistent with my system having a Radeon card.

Comment: I can't really make sense of the content in `Xorg.0.log`, but I have not found anything that hints to integrated graphics being used. `glxinfo` prints: `OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series` even though I'm just browsing the web.

Comment: So, I will assume that the graphics switching is not working.

Comment: it would be useful if you could join the hybrid-graphics-linux launchpad team and provide the DSDT info for your laptop: http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux